# How ObjectDeletion works in java card?

Tags: java, javacard

Below, you see a program that I wrote to see the state of different fields and memory allocations after calling `requestObjectDeletion()` method:

```
public class ReqObjDel extends Applet {
    static byte[] buffer = new byte[2];
    static boolean isNull = false;

    private ReqObjDel() {
    }

    public static void install(byte bArray[], short bOffset, byte bLength)
            throws ISOException {
        new ReqObjDel().register();
    }

    public void process(APDU arg0) throws ISOException {
        if (selectingApplet()) {
            return;
        }

        if (buffer != null && (short) buffer.length == (short) 10) {
            return;
        }

        byte[] oldBuffer = buffer;
        buffer = new byte[10];

        JCSystem.requestObjectDeletion();

        if (oldBuffer == null)
            isNull = true;

        if (isNull) {
            ISOException.throwIt((short) 0x1111);
        } else
            ISOException.throwIt((short) 0x0000);
    }
}
```

As far as I know,this method reclaims memory which is being used by “unreachable” objects. To be “unreachable”, an object can neither be pointed to                by a static field nor by an object field. So calling                           `requestObjectDeletion()` in the above program reclaims the part of EEPROM that `oldBuffer` is refer to (As far as I know, `oldBuffer` is neither class field nor object field,right?). In this situation I expect that `oldBuffer == null` and therefore the JCRE must return `0x1111`. But the output is `0x0000` unexpectedly :

```
OSC: opensc-tool -s 00a404000b0102030405060708090000 -s 00000000
Using reader with a card: ACS CCID USB Reader 0
Sending: 00 A4 04 00 0B 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 00 00
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00)
Sending: 00 00 00 00
Received (SW1=0x00, SW2=0x00)
```

**Q1 :** What can I conclude?

- That part of memory is not reclaimed?
- That part of memory is reclaimed **but** `oldBuffer` is a reference to it still?
- something else?

**Q2 :** Is there any way to obtain the free memory size before and after of calling this method? (i.e. is there any method that return the size of free memory[not allocated]?)

---

**Update 1 : Trying `JCSystem.getAvailableMemory()`**

Based on @vojta answer, I changed my program in a way that the line `byte[] oldBuffer = buffer;` runs only once (using a flag named `isFirstInvocation`) and return the free available memory in two consecutive `process()` method invocation :

```
public class ReqObjDel extends Applet {
    static byte[] buffer = new byte[10];
    static boolean isFirstInvocation = true;

    private ReqObjDel() {
    }

    public static void install(byte bArray[], short bOffset, byte bLength)
            throws ISOException {
        new ReqObjDel().register();
    }

    public void process(APDU arg0) throws ISOException {
        if (selectingApplet()) {
            return;
        }

        short availableMem1 = JCSystem
                .getAvailableMemory(JCSystem.MEMORY_TYPE_PERSISTENT);

        if (isFirstInvocation) {

            byte[] oldBuffer = buffer;

            buffer = new byte[10];

            JCSystem.requestObjectDeletion();

            firstInvocation = false;
        }

        short availableMem2 = JCSystem
                .getAvailableMemory(JCSystem.MEMORY_TYPE_PERSISTENT);

        short availableMemory = (short) (availableMem1 + availableMem2);
        ISOException.throwIt(availableMemory);

    }
}
```

And this is the output :

```
OSC: osc -s 00a404000b0102030405060708090000 -s 00000000 -s 00000000
Using reader with a card: ACS CCID USB Reader 0
Sending: 00 A4 04 00 0B 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 00 00
Received (SW1=0x90, SW2=0x00)
Sending: 00 00 00 00
Received (SW1=0xFF, SW2=0xFE)
Sending: 00 00 00 00
Received (SW1=0xFF, SW2=0xFE)
```

As both invocations return an equal value, I think the JCRE reclaims that part of memory immediately after calling `requestObjectDeletion()`, right?

Comment: Why do you sum availableMem1 and availableMem2?

Comment: @vojta I don't remember! give me some minutes! I think returning  the sum of them is more reliable that returning availableMem1 only or availableMem2 only!

Comment: More reliable? Why? Your availableMem1 == 32767, your availableMem2 == 32767, together it is a negative number (short is signed) 0xFFFE, but I think all relevant information is gone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, a rule based on my personal experience: if possible, **do not use the garbage collector at all**. GC is very slow and could be even dangerous (see [Javacard - power loss during garbage collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28147582/javacard-power-loss-during-garbage-collection)).

**Q1:**
If you really have to use GC, read the documentation:

> This method is invoked by the applet to trigger the object deletion
>   service of the Java Card runtime environment. If the Java Card runtime
>   environment implements the object deletion mechanism, the request is
>   merely logged at this time. The Java Card runtime environment must
>   schedule the object deletion service **prior to the next invocation** of
>   the Applet.process() method.

Shortly speaking, `JCSystem.requestObjectDeletion();` has no immediate effect. That is why your local variable `oldBuffer` remains unchanged.

**Q2:** To find out how much persistent memory is available to your applet, use:

```
JCSystem.getAvailableMemory(JCSystem.MEMORY_TYPE_PERSISTENT)
```

**ANSWER to UPDATE 1:** `JCSystem.getAvailableMemory(JCSystem.MEMORY_TYPE_PERSISTENT)` may be confusing for cards with more than 32767 bytes of persistent memory. Such cards usually offer their own proprietary ways to find out available memory.

> If the number of available bytes is greater than 32767, then this
>   method returns 32767.

Comment: Thanks for your advice._JCRE schedule the object deletion service prior to the next invocation of the Applet.process() method._.OK. So if I add another flag to my program and run the line `byte[] oldBuffer = buffer;` in the first `process()` method invocation only, I must receive `0x0001` in second invocation? right?

Comment: Or I can use `JCSystem.getAvailableMemory(JCSystem.MEMORY_TYPE_PERSISTENT)` in the start and end of `process()` method to compare the value of free memory in the **end of first invocation** with the free memory at the **start of second invocation** to see the `ObjectioDeletion` method, right?

Comment: Question updated. I used two variable named `availableMem1 ` and `availableMem2 ` in the start and end of `process()` method and return the sum of the at the end of this method. the returns are equal! I think this mean that `requestObjectDeletion()` method reclaim the memory immediately, right? (I changed initial value of static `buffer` also)

Comment: It's a JCOP with 64k EEPROM. So what now? I couldn't implement the first applet with `isFirstInvocation` flag (Because when I use `if (isFirstInvocation)`, the scope of `oldBuffer` is limited to this `if` scope and I can't change the value of `inNull` anymore). Do you have any idea?

Comment: @Jean What are you trying to do? To find a proof that GC works? Well I am quite sure it does - you can create longer arrays to get under 32767 remaining bytes... Your `oldBuffer` is always limited to `process` method. What is your goal? I see no difference, you can put the whole process method into if block.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73172/discussion-between-vojta-and-jean).

Comment: I want to see if it works fine or not. I want to be sure that the oldBuffer change to `null`. I'll update the question and inform you. I don't want to put the whole process method into the `if (isFirstInvocation)` block! I want `if (oldBuffer == null) {isNull = true;} if (isNull) {ISOException.throwIt((short) 0x1111);} else {ISOException.throwIt((short) 0x0000);}` to be outside!