# How do I know the rest amount of memory is available to my applet

Tags: smartcard, javacard

My applet is used as a simple file system  in java card. So it will allocated  memory  dynamicly. And when the rest amount of memory isn't enough, it will recycle the memory . so how do I know the rest amount of memory is available to my applet

Comment: My personal experience: do NOT use garbage collector at all! It is slow and even dangerous - it can damage your card. Use one large byte array instead and implement your own allocation, defragmentation etc. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28147582/javacard-power-loss-during-garbage-collection

Answer (score 1):

Is this method the method that you want?

Quoted from *Java Card platform, Version 3.0.1, Classic Specification*:

> **getAvailableMemory(byte memoryType)**
>
> `public static short getAvailableMemory(byte memoryType) throws SystemException`
>
> Obtains the amount of memory of the specified type that is available to the applet. Note that  implementation-dependent memory overhead structures may also use the same memory pool.
>
> Notes:
>
> • The number of bytes returned is only an upper bound on the amount of memory available due to  overhead requirements.
>
> • Allocation of CLEAR_ON_RESET transient objects may affect the amount of CLEAR_ON_DESELECT  transient memory available.
>
> • Allocation of CLEAR_ON_DESELECT transient objects may affect the amount of CLEAR_ON_RESET  transient memory available.
>
> • If the number of available bytes is greater than 32767, then this method returns 32767.
>
> • The returned count is not an indicator of the size of object which may be created since memory  fragmentation is possible.
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> memoryType - the type of memory being queried. One of the MEMORY_TYPE_* constants defined  above. See MEMORY_TYPE_PERSISTENT .
>
> **Returns:**
>
> the upper bound on available bytes of memory for the specified type
>
> **Throws:**
>
> SystemException_ with the following reason codes:
>
> • SystemException.ILLEGAL_VALUE if memoryType is not a valid memory type.

You can simply call this method and based on its output, decide to recycle or allocate or release some bytes of memory.

*Note that as dear [npostas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/319698/) mentioned in his/her comment,JavaCard version 3.0.4 adds a `getAvailableMemory(short[] buffer, short offset, byte memoryType)` method which can return a 32 bit number into a short array.*

*(JCOP cards have a proprietary API for that also)*